# Is there a difference in Ubuntu 32 bit vs. 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

Because I accidentally installed 32 bit, and I used 64 bit last time. I'm not sure, it bugs me. Any reassurance?

Answer (score 0):

If your CPU's architecture is 64-bit then you should install a 64-bit OS. You computer will be using its full potential and will be much faster than the 32-bit one.

Comment: Okay Thank you! How do I do that, though? I put 64-bit on a flash drive to do so. However, upon removing it last time, I left out some GB sitting to the side that I can't for the life of me fix. >.< I don't have anything of value to back up; so I'm willing to do whatever to get to 64-bit correctly; I jut want to dual boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have less than 4GB of RAM then it doesn't hurt to use 32-bit.  If you have 1GB or more however you really: [should be](http://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/) using 64-bit.  The choice also depends on whether or not your hardware is capable of 64-bit, if it is then you should use 64-bit.

Comment: And, yes, 1GB or more you should use 64-bit.  Read the article about how virtual memory maps into a system for the why.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I have over 100GB of space to use up. :) However, upon removing Ubuntu last time; I still have leftover space that I don't know how to add onto the current space I have.

Comment: -1 Telling someone to install a 64bit system on anything greater than 1GB is poor advice, as 64bit applications have a larger memory footprint, the rule of thumb for benefits is really around 4GB, especially for someone who multitasks or leaves applications open all the time. See the linked duplicate above for more information.

Comment: Did you bother to read the linked article?  At *1GB* you start to get issues with virtual memory that switching to 64-bit addressing fixes.

Comment: n00bs don't even know when they are being given good advice on non.  After my brief sojourn here I'm back to Arch - where incompetence isn't rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that there aren't really any **super horrible** repercussions for using a 32 bit on a 64 bit,

but as was said before, you wont be using your computer's full potential.

It's like a bus driver with a capacity of 64 people on his bus, but he only picks up 32 and leaves for the next stop, leaving the rest of the people [he could have] picked up waiting for the next time.

Its just not economical or making good use of your computer ; anyway, I hope my analogy helped.   :)